# Is it possible to run a SQL-only file from a "rake db:create"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm trying to install a software called [Teambox](http://teambox.com) in my Dreamhost shared account, following [these instructions](http://wiki.github.com/micho/teambox/installing-locally).

I have no experience with Rails. I just want to install the software in the shared hosting.

In this shared hosting, all dependencies are ok, but I have to create the dabatase from their panel. I can't create in command line (ssh).

So, when I run "rake db:create" these's an error, because the db already exists (because I created in panel).

I've already contacted support. They can't change this policy.

How do I populate my tables "by hand" in this case? Which files should I look inside Teambox's folder...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rake db:create` should create your database and that's all. It doesn't creates your tables.
There are several rake tasks to do that :

- `rake db:migrate` which will execute your migrations. So create all your tables.
- `rake db:seed` which will add the original data of your application. See [Database Seeding](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/5/13/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-database-seeding)

You don't need to be able to create the database to do any of these.

Comment: I'm new to Ruby/Rails stuff. I was just planning to install and get running. The app wiki is "rake db:create db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=development". So, should I change it to "rake db:migrate"?

Comment: Just run `rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=development` if the database already exists.